# Undefined symbol:WriteFloat

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

Undefined symbol:WriteFloat

```
; Implementation of the following expression:
; (6.0 * 2.0) + (4.5 * 3.2)
; FPU instructions used.

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc    ; 32-bit Protected mode program.
Include Macros.inc

.data
    array REAL4 6.0, 2.0, 4.5, 3.2
    dotProduct REAL4 ?
    val BYTE ?

.code
main PROC

    finit               ; initialize FPU
    fld array           ; push 6.0 onto the stack
    fmul array+4        ; ST(0) = 6.0 * 2.0
    fld array+8         ; push 4.5 onto the stack
    fmul array+12       ; ST(0) = 4.5 * 3.2
    fadd                ; ST(0) = ST(0) + ST(1)
    fstp dotProduct     ; pop stack into memory operand
    call WriteFloat

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

My code is working. The issue is just the WriteFloat. When I change the WriteFloat to WriteInt or WriteDec, there is no error. But i can't get my exact result. I have the Irvine32.lib, Macros.inc and I'm using masm615 and my editor is textpad.

Comment: Shouldn't you have an `INCLUDELIB "Irvine32.lib"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
fstp dotProduct
```

to

```
fst dotProduct
```

WriteFloat uses the value on the stack, but fstp removes the value from the stack. fst (without "p") lets the value on the stack.